# Post Anonymous object to MVC Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a MVC application where I need to expose a Action that will take 2 param. The first param will be string type and second will be an object. Based on first param value I will parse the object. I am trying to do something like this

Client Side

```
function SaveLookup() {
    debugger;
    var userData = {};
    userData.lookupType = "Users";
    userData.objLookup = { "UserID": 1, "UserCode": "XYZ", "FirstName": "FName", "LastName": "LNAme", "IsActive": "1", "UserRole": "2" };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/SaveLookup',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(userData),
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            $("#partialviews").html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            debugger;
            alert(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

Server Side

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveLookup(string lookupType, object objLookup)
    {

        if (lookupType == "Users")
            User uObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(objLookup);
        else if (lookupType == "xyz")

        return Json("");
    }
```

I am able to read the first param value but not able to parse the object. I tried the reflection but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried using the dynamic data type instead of object?

Comment: Have you tried this: `var uObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(objLookup);`, then assign variable from deserialized object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mohd Ansari, it seems like problem in your client side script.

Use client side as

```
function SaveLookup() {
    debugger;
    var userData = {};
    userData.lookupType = "Users";
    userData.objLookup =  JSON.stringify({ "UserID": 1, "UserCode": "XYZ", "FirstName": "FName", "LastName": "LNAme", "IsActive": "1", "UserRole": "2" });
  //  console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/SaveLookup',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(userData),
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            debugger;
            alert(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

and your controller code should be

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveLookup(string lookupType, string objLookup)
    {
        User uObject = new User();
        if (lookupType == "Users")
           uObject =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(objLookup);
        return Json("");
    }
```

Let me know is that logic works for you ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but I don't want to make the second param typed.. I need to use it as anonymous object.. that's why I am using 2 parameters. First will tell me the type and based on that I will deserialized the object.

Comment: @MohdAnsari, I update answer now try, you can pass any dynamic object and convert it in controller as per your need.

Comment: you knocked it.. there is no need to change the type of objLookup.. it is working great with object type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see.

```
var itemsSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objLookup);
User uObject = (User)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(itemsSerialized);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (use **dynamic**) `public JsonResult SaveLookup(string lookupType, dynamic objLookup)`